# Vim extension for VSCode : remap ^

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vim-plugin

I am looking to rebind the `^` shortcut in normal mode (goes to the first non-whitespace character of the line), to use `q` instead. However, I can't seem to find the name of the command that is appropriated for this : I have tried `"commands": ['cursorLineStart']` but this goes to the beginning of the line, including whitespace characters, which is not what I want.

Does anyone know the exact name of the command associated with `^` ?

Comment: Documentation for VSCodeVim key bindings can be found at: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim##key-remapping

Comment: I could only find the extension's settings on that page, not the actual list of vim commands

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking but would this suffice:

```
nnoremap q ^
```

Edit:

Adding an operator pending motion so OP can do things like *dq* as mentioned in the comments.

```
onoremap q ^
```

Comment: I thought of doing that, the only problem is that this doesn't work when I chain commands, ex : `q` will be equivalent to `^` but `dq` will not be equivalent to `d^` (at least that is how the vscode extension works)

Comment: Ah right, then you need an operator pending motion too. I'll update the answer with that.